# Why $|A_1 - A_2| + |B_1 - B_2|$ would not be greater than both $|A_1 - B_1| + |A_2 - B_2|$ and $|B_1 - A_2| + |A_1 - B_2|$ at the same time?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Here is an example:

$A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2 = 5, 8, 0, 9$ respectively

$|A_1 - A_2| + |B_1 - B_2| = 12$

$|A_1 - B_1| + |A_2 - B_2| = 6$

$|B_1 - A_2| + |A_1 - B_2| = 12$

For any $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, $|A_1 - A_2| + |B_1 - B_2|$ would not be greater than both of the other two sums. How can this be proven?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a,b,c,d)$ be a permutation of $(A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2)$ such that $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$. Then each of the sums
\begin{align}
X&=|A_1-A_2|+|B_1-B_2|, \\
Y&=|A_1-B_1|+|A_2-B_2|, \\
Z&=|B_1-A_2|+|A_1-B_2|,
\end{align} corresponds to one of the sums
\begin{align}
x&=(b-a)+(d-c), \\
y&=(c-a)+(d-b), \\
z&=(d-a)+(c-b).
\end{align}
Clearly, $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$. In addition,
\begin{align}
y&=((c-b)+(b-a))+((d-c)+(c-b))=(b-a)+2(c-b)+(d-c), \\
z&=((d-c)+(c-b)+(b-a))+(c-b)=(b-a)+2(c-b)+(d-c),
\end{align}
so $y=z$. It follows, therefore, that the largest two sums among $X,Y,Z$ are equal, so none of them is greater than the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x := A_1 - A_2, y := B_1 - B_2$.

By triangle inequality, we have
$$|A_1 - B_1| + |A_2 - B_2|
\ge |A_1 - B_1 - (A_2 - B_2)| = |x - y|$$
and
$$|B_1 - A_2| + |A_1 - B_2|
\ge |B_1 - A_2 + A_1 - B_2| = |x + y|.$$

If $xy \ge 0$, then $|x + y| = |x| + |y|$.
If $xy < 0$, then $|x - y| = |x| + |y|$.

Thus, it is impossible that
$|A_1 - A_2| + |B_1 - B_2| > |A_1 - B_1| + |A_2 - B_2|$ and $|A_1 - A_2| + |B_1 - B_2|
> |B_1 - A_2| + |A_1 - B_2|$ at the same time.